# python replace stand alone string using inputs

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have 2 fields in a pandas dataframe. I would like to remove the string value in 'var1' with the value in 'var2' but only if the value is stand alone in 'var1' (not WITHIN a word). For example, in the string in var1 = "APPLE AP", replace the value in var2 "AP" so that the final value is "APPLE". The current code results in a returned value of "PLE":

```
 var1 = pd.Series(['APPLE AP','CO COMPANY CO','CO COMPANY CO','DR','CAT'])

    var2 = pd.Series(['AP','CO','COMPANY','DR',' '])

    var1_expected_output = pd.Series(['APPLE','COMPANY','CO CO',' ','CAT'])

    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(var1= var1,var2= var2 ,var1_expected_output=var1_expected_output))

   #correct this part:  df['var1_incorrect_output'] = df.apply(lambda x:  x['var1'].replace( x['var2'], ''), axis=1)

    df = df[['var1','var2','var1_expected_output','var1_incorrect_output']]

    print df

    var1            var2      var1_expected_output  var1_incorrect_output
0   APPLE AP        AP        APPLE                 PLE
1   CO COMPANY CO   CO        COMPANY               MPANY
2   CO COMPANY CO   COMPANY   CO CO                 CO  CO
3   DR  DR      
4   CAT                       CAT                   CAT
```

FYI: The lambda snippet of code is part of a much large project with hundred of millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

#### `apply` + `re.sub`

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : var1, 'var2' : var2})        
df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(x.var2), '', x.var1), 1)

0       APPLE 
1     COMPANY 
2       CO  CO
3             
4          CAT
dtype: object
```

Slow, but guaranteed to work

---

#### `set` difference

Should be faster, but not guaranteed to work (since sets don't keep order or duplicates)

```
(var1.str.split().apply(set) - var2.str.split().apply(set)).str.join(' ')

0      APPLE
1    COMPANY
2         CO    # fails here
3           
4        CAT
dtype: object
```